# Can valgrind pick up a memory leak in a static library that im using from a C executable in a separate directory?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, static-libraries, valgrind, libraries

I made a main.c file in a static library to test if my static library works (it contains a main function/method of course which uses the library) and so my library was functional. Then I used that library in a C file say, *myprog* from another directory. I intentionally put a memory leak into the static library, then returned to the other directory and ran *myprog* through Valgrind to see if could pick it up. It could not. Why? When I went back to main.c and ran that through Valgrind the intentional leak was showing but not in *myprog*.

I find this rather fascinating. Why is this happening and can someone confirm if my findings are correct?

Comment: Did you re-compile the static library and then program, after changing the static library?

Comment: Yes I am sure I did.

Comment: Does "myprog" have its own main function?

Comment: Yes indeed myprog has its own main function. ( main.c was in the library and that was just for testing the methods)

Comment: Keep in mind that the static library one won't be used then. It does sound like you simply haven't recompiled/relinked something.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean. The main.c file in the static library has no methods apart from the main method in order to test the methods in another file say, functionality.c

Comment: I just meant the static library's main function won't be used because the one from myprog takes priority.

Comment: I know that's not an issue the static library's main function is a test to see if the library is working. The point is that when there is a leak in functionality.c this is not shown in the separate directory that is really using the library. In order for me to test that the leak in the library shows up, in the separate directory I tested if I could see the leak using a main method (main.c) which the same directory as the library and I could. So then I ran the real program which used the library through valgrind and surprisingly it didn't say there was a leak.

Comment: Valgrind is currently not operational on macOS Sierra, which is a nuisance to me.  However, I'd be astonished if Valgrind could not spot the leak; it is not affected by the location of the static library since the relevant object code is in the executable anyway.  Personally, I'd need to see your MCVE ([MCVE]) and the Valgrind output before I was remotely convinced.  The 'library' could be trivial — one function: `void *allocate(size_t nbytes) { printf("Allocating %zu bytes\n", nbytes); return malloc(nbytes); }` _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ The main function could be approximately equally trivial: `extern void *allocate(size_t nbytes); int main(void) { void *vp = allocate(16); printf("Allocated %p\n", vp); return 0; }`.  Compile the library code into a static library.  Compile the main code and link with the static library.  Run under Valgrind.  This should demonstrate Valgrind spotting the leak.

Comment: Apologies, please see the edit above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**:
Short answer: YES valgrind can pick up memory leaks in a static library.

**Reason**:
Apologies. I'm new to CMake. And after purposefully adding a memory leak to the library I recompiled (or so I thought) I didn't know that I had to delete all the associated CMake files before recompiling (which is really annoying) I assumed typing `cmake .` and then `make` was sufficient) but its not.

What I should've done in the directory that uses the static library is 
run
 `make clean` then `make`